# Spring MVC app breaks when I add config for json

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

When I add this chunk of code to my servlet-config.xml, it breaks my Spring MVC app. I've had troubles in the past with wrong version dependencies, so I wonder if that's the problem.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
<property name="order" value="1" />
<property name="contentNegotiationManager">
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager">
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.accept.PathExtensionContentNegotiationStrategy">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <map>
                        <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
                        <entry key="xml" value="application/xml" />
                    </map>
                </constructor-arg>
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
</property>

<property name="defaultViews">
    <list>
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView" />
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xml.MarshallingView">
            <constructor-arg>
                <bean class="org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller">
                    <property name="autodetectAnnotations" value="true" />
                </bean>
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>
    </list>
</property> </bean>
```

This is my servlet-config.xml that works before I try to add in the above piece to process json.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <mvc:resources location="pdfs" mapping="/pdfs/**"/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.pluralsight"/>

    <mvc:interceptors>
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor" p:paramName="language"/>
    </mvc:interceptors>

    <bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver" p:defaultLocale="en"/>

    <bean id="messageSource" 
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource" 
    p:basename="messages"></bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" 
     p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/" p:suffix=".jsp" p:order="2"/>

     <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver" p:order="0"/>

</beans>
```

This is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>fitTrackerServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/servlet-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>fitTrackerServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>fitTrackerServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/pdfs/**</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

        <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>fitTrackerServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.json</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
</web-app>
```

This is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.pluralsight</groupId>
  <artifactId>FitnessTracker</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>FitnessTracker Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
        <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>FitnessTracker</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

The error is:

```
root cause

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver#0' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/servlet-config.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView#a01c402' of type [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView] while setting bean property 'defaultViews' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView] for bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView#a01c402' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/servlet-config.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:290)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:122)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:157)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1471)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1216)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:725)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:663)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:629)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:677)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:548)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:489)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: What's the error msg you getting?

Comment: just posted error, thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For Spring framework ver 4.1.x, you are using Jackson2,  instead of Jackson1.

Please try replacing

```
MappingJacksonJsonView
```

to

```
MappingJackson2JsonView
```

Comment: Thanks, that got me on the right track. I also needed to add:  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
     <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
     <version>2.3.2</version>
 </dependency> to my pom.xml and then it worked.

Comment: The bean will then looks like:
`<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJackson2JsonView">
    <property name="contentType" value="application/json"/>
</bean>`

Comment: But if I add com.fasterxml.jackson.core as dependency, the tomcat server is getting stopped. what is the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Adding solution from @Dust Francis works But I got few errors But
 changing Spring framework (spring-mvc and spring-oxm ) to same version resolved the issue for me. The pom.xml look like

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.navroop</groupId>
  <artifactId>FitnessTracker</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>FitnessTracker Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.9.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
      <version>6.1.0.Alpha6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
      <version>2.10.0.pr1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
      <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.11.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>FitnessTracker</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```